# How to customize LXQt theming on 16.04

Tags: 16.04, themes, lxqt

I have installed LXQt via the `lxqt-metapackage` and while it seems like a grand desktop environment, I can't seem to customize it. I Google searched for ways to customize its themes and such and found [this link](https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=LXQt_Theming). It suggested that LXQt has some configuration centre, which I can't seem to find on Ubuntu. I have tried searching `/usr/bin` for `lxqt` (using `ls /usr/bin | grep lxqt`) and the closest command I could find to a configuration centre was `lxqt-config-session`, which has no theming options.

I also ran `sudo apt-cache search lxqt | grep config` and found the `lxqt-config` package which I attempted to install, but this failed leading to this error:

```
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

No files to download.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lxqt-config : Depends: libkf5screen6 (>= 5.1.1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have Kubuntu also installed, and from what I can gather `libkf5screen6`
conflicts with `libkf5screen7` which I have installed.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes if you have 16.04 installed and want libkfscreen7 installed which is not in the regular ubuntu repos I think you might have backported it for a more recent version of kde as I know the kubuntu team does backports. 
And yes the configuration center is part of the lxqt-config package. This is a danger of installing PPAs on your system in that you can have other packages with conflicts from new versions https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PPA . However lxqt-config in yakkety is http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/lxqt-config shows the dependences in xenial and http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/lxqt-config shows the dependencies. If you have other packages that depend on libkf5screen7 then you will not run into this problem on yakkety. I don't see a reason you would install the the libkf5screen7 on xenial without dependencies on it as it a library then you could  sudo apt-get remove libkfscreen7. Although you can see if you use anything that depends on it with apt-cache rdepends libkf5screen7 and if you don't have anything you can remove it. This is a case of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell. If you remove the things that depend on libkf5screen7 you then can remove it and then install lxqt-config. However this will not happen on yakkety but yakkety is not a long term support release.